# Gaussian Decoherence - How to (mathematically) arrive at this statement?

Tags: decoherence

This question regards [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0611200.pdf) paper by Zurek, Cucchietti and Paz from 2008 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.quant-ph/0611200), in specific how to arrive at (12) from (10) and (11) (please see the paper itself). This seems to be straight forward math, but I don't get it. Therefore I will summarize what is written in the paper:

> Equation (10) gives the decoherence factor for a special "simple"
> model, that the authors use:
>
> $$r(t)=\sum_{l=0}^N {N\choose
> l}|\alpha|^{2(N-l)}|\beta|^{2l}e^{ig(N-2l)t}\tag{10}$$
>
> Where $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$ and both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are
> complex numbers.
>
> Equation (11) gives the Gaussian approximation of the factor
>
> $${N\choose l}|\alpha|^{2(N-l)}|\beta|^{2l}\approx \frac{1}{2\pi
> N|\alpha\beta|^2}e^{-\frac{(l-N|\beta|^2)^2}{2N|\alpha\beta|^2}}\tag{11}$$
>
> This (according to the authors) immediately yields the result, given
> in equation (12):
>
> $$|r(t)|=e^{-2N|\alpha\beta|^2(gt)^2}\tag{12}$$.

Substituting (11) in (10) and taking the absolute value doesn't seem to do it. Somehow (by arriving at (12)) there have been made several steps I seem to not fully understand. Can anyone explain to me what is happening here?

A second question adds to this. Equation (10) is a special case ($\alpha_k=\alpha,g_k=g$) of the more general equation (9):

$$r(t)=\prod_{k=1}^N|\alpha_k|^2e^{it\sum_ng_n}+\sum_{l=1}^N|\beta_l|^2\prod_{k\neq l}^N|\alpha_k|^2\times e^{it(-g_l+\sum_{n\neq l}g_n)}+\sum_{l=1}^N\sum_{m\neq l}^N |\beta_l|^2|\beta_m|^2\times \prod_{k\neq l,m}^N |\alpha_k|^2 e^{[it(-g_l-g_m+\sum_{n\neq l,m}^Ng_n)]}+...\tag{9}$$

which came from a re-expression of $r(t)$, namely

$$r(t)=\prod_{k=1}^N \left(|\alpha_k|^2e^{ig_kt}+|\beta_k|^2e^{-ig_kt}\right)$$.

With what is said in the blockquote above, the authors tried to make it more clear that $r(t)$ (as in (9) - the general variant) is of Gaussian nature. But is it really? Somehow (9) must be a generalized binomial pattern, I haven't seen before.